# Expected to find element : but never found it(not a normal assertion)

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

//I have tried alias,asserts,wait,etc..,but can't click the element because the page is not loaded.I don't want to use wait() or pause() command.
I need a solution to interact with the elements however the network or testing environment is slow or speed.

My code is as follows :

///

it('Test ship',function(){

```
cy.viewport(1120,800)

  cy.visit('url')

 cy.get('#NFR_LoginForm-nfr_login_authname').type('KKV2C123')

 cy.get('#NFR_LoginForm-nfr_login_authid').type('paSSword1{enter}')

 cy.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
     return false
 })
 
 cy.wait[ cy.xpath('//span[normalize-space()="Work Space"]')
      
           .click({force: true})]
```

Here is my screenshot.

[Assertion error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Wqm.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `cy.wait[]` is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bump the wait time on your click(). Is 3 minutes enough?

```js
cy.xpath('//span[normalize-space()="Work Space"]', {timeout:180000})
  .click()
```

Comment: The increase of wait can make the element clicked.But by not waiting can u give me a solution.I don't want to use wait and pause.

Comment: Cypress' use of "waiting" isn't the same as Selenium's. In this case, if the element is found in under 3 minutes, then the test will resume. The `timeout` only tells Cypress a maximum amount of time to wait, not an exact amount of time to wait.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along these lines below:

```
...
cy.visit('http://70.207.7.25:8070/main')
// mark our window object to "know" when it gets loaded
cy.window().then(w => w.beforeLoad = true)
// initially the new property is there
cy.window().should('have.prop', 'beforeLoad', true)
// after reload the property should be gone
cy.window().should('not.have.prop', 'beforeLoad')
...
```

This will give a `window a new property` which will be tracked on page switch and should give it kind of a "pause" to wait for the `property not to be available after page loads`

Comment: I have tried but couldn't solve the error.The page is taking nearly 85 sec to load.I dont want to add cy.wait(80000).Can you say me another solution.

Comment: Sorry but nothing else comes to mind as the only other solution is actually timeout (wait or pause)

Comment: its ok.U did ur best to help me out.Thank u